# Closed-form solution for $f(x)/x=y$ using $f^{-1}$

Tags: functions, closed-form, applications, inverse-function

I'm programming a piece of math that requires solving an equation of a form $f(x)/x=y$. Now I already have $f^{-1}(z)$ coded (efficiently, and not by me) so I'd prefer using this implementation instead of, say, coding bisection for $f(x)/x$. Is there a way to do that?

If it were $f(x)=y$, I would just use $x=f^{-1}(y)$. But with $f(x)/x=y$ I doubt it's even possible to have a closed-form solution with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ but I can't come up with a reasoning for that.

Comment: What is formula for $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath, it's very large and clumsy and is constructed in several steps. It's not the first time I faced this problem, previously with different expressions for $f(x)$, so I'm asking a question in general, for arbitrary $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in general.  For example, if $f(x) = e^x$ then $f^{-1}(x) = \log x$.  But the solution $x$ of
$$
\frac{e^x}{x} = y
$$
is not elementary:
$$
x = -W\left(\frac{-1}{y}\right)
$$
where W is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
Knowing how to compute $e^x$ and $\log x$ does not tell you how to compute this solution.

Comment: Thanks, that answers it